# other way to check if value is null or empty and assign value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest))
           newString = stringTest; // newString is a string
 else
           newString = string.Empty;
```

Is there another (simple) way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean simplier way like ternary operator `?` which is `newString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest) ? string.Empty : stringTest` or the `IsNullOrEmpty` itself?

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez , yep .. indeed. My fault, I found the ? operator documentation right after I commit the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the Null-coalescence operator:

```
newString = stringTest ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: I was looking for the ?? operator. Is it better to use the ?? than the ? operatoR? ( in my case )

Comment: Resharper is what you need! @FlorinM.

Comment: Well, what means "better"? It's shorter for this precise condition. However, the ? operator is more flexible if you have other conditions.

Comment: Let say I have a DateTime? dateExample. I tried myNewdate = dateExample ?? // ... ?

Comment: @FlorinM. (your last comment) So what do you want if `dateExample` is null?

Comment: Assign a null value to a date time. I used just null and it seems it works

Comment: ?? means if value is null then assign something else to it. otherwise keep it. `dateExample ?? null` makes no sense and can be simplified to `dateExample`... another example `dateExample ?? new DateTime()` means if `dateExample` is null put `new DateTime()` otherwise keep `dateExample` @FlorinM.

Comment: I meant : myNewdate = dateExample ?? null;

Comment: @FlorinM. That is silly, just say `myNewdate = dateExample;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I see. So, if myNewDate is a DateTime? and if dateExample is null, then from your line of code => myNewdate is null ?

Comment: @FlorinM. yes. use of `??` is prevention from value being null.

Comment: I understand. But if I want to "combine" 3 values: If a is null then b = c , else b = null , I can not use ?? anymore, right?

Comment: @FlorinM. no. its not possible.you can use ternary : `b = a == null ? c : b`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary amazing tips for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[C# Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
newString = String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest) ? String.Empty : stringTest;
```

You can use [Null Coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator too:-

```
newString = stringTest ?? String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
string newString = String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest) ? string.Empty : stringTest;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set to `""` since it's the same as `String.Empty` and it's much more readable and faster to type.

`newString = stringTest ?? "";`

Double quotes will not create a new string according the specification [2.4.4.5 String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx)

> Each string literal does not necessarily result in a new string instance. When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator (Section 7.9.7) appear in the same assembly, these string literals refer to the same string instance.

Comment: It's not the same in terms of what it does. Using `string.Empty` reuses an existing string object while using `""` creates a new empty string object.

Comment: @StevenLiekens No, when `""` appears in the source code, a string with that value will be ***interned***, which means that this same instance will be used every time `""` occurs.

Comment: That might be true for versions older than .NET 2.0 but after that there is essentially no difference.See [2.4.4.5 String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx) for specification.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this too

if (stringTest.Length > 0)
           newString = stringTest; 
else 
           newString = string.Empty;

if (!stringTest == null)
           newString = stringTest; 
else 
           newString = string.Empty;

if (!stringTest == "")
           newString = stringTest; 
else 
           newString = string.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

```
newString = String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest)?String.Empty : stringTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple than that?... Nope.

Here's another option, but it's basically the same.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTest) == false ? newString = stringTest : newString = String.Empty;
```